# How to detect the integrity of bigdata

Tags: database, nosql, bigdata

Suppose that I have a table，Where there are N pieces of data，namely row1, row2, · ·, rowN. How can I detect these data have not been changed illegally?

I mean we can do the hash function for each of the data, such as：

```
TABLE

row1    hash(row1)
row2    hash(row2)

· · ·
rowN    hash(rowN)
```

When I want to know whether these data have been changed illegally, I can just traverse all the data to see whether the hash value of the rowi is equal to the original hash(rowi).

But if there are a lot of data, the traversing is very time-consuming, I want to know whether there is any other method to detect the integrity of bigdata?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some solutions:

1. Field with control/check sum (lightweight, simple operation like sum or div/mod by X) or hashing (as you wrote)
2. Provide only insert and delete operation on database + audit log table/entity (one row in table is one package of inserts)
3. Use AutoUpdate Fiels: CreateTimeStamp & ModifyTimestamp - if the database provide this type of fields - and compare

In BigData approach I recommend option 2.